# How to get C code to print to output file?

Tags: c

I have a code that sorts a list, I can get it to sort when the list is hardcoded. I am now attempting to implement getting the list from an input file and running it the same way through the code then printing it to an output file. I am trying to get a scanned list from an input file to go through what I have (that is working) for sorting and for the result to be printed to an output file.

Comment: malloc for 20+1

Comment: gotta account for null string '\0' otherwise compiler won't know where string ends

Comment: There's no need to use `malloc()` for `temp()`. You only need dynamic allocation for the copy that you insert into the list.

Comment: Your code doesn't use the filenames in `argv`, it always opens the hard-coded filenames.

Comment: As ever, first check the compiler warnings. `fprintf(ofp, "flags are (%d, %d).\n", &cflag, &dflag);` has incorrect `&` operaters.

Comment: guys i actually tried to run the code, many errors. op is probably unaware of ```-Wall``` flag and is not being notified of any errors

Comment: Aside: don't hard-code things like `if(tmp->data[i] >= 97 && tmp->data[i] <= 122) { tmp->data[i] = tmp->data[i] - 32; }`. Use `if(islower(tmp->data[i])) { tmp->data[i] = toupper(tmp->data[i]); }`

Comment: to op: ```gcc -std=c99 -Wall myfile.c myfile2.c -o myfile.exe```

Comment: The flags are just there for testing purposes and I will remove them afterwards. I am just really not sure how to fix this and get it to print to a file, I have spent hours and am completely lost at this point. Really a beginner so I'm not sure how it should be fixed.

Comment: You are assigning ifp to stdout, meaning you app will not be able to read anything. Did you intend to assign ofp instead? (send output to console instead of file)

Comment: I am trying to get it to output to a file but to a console would work as well.

Comment: That code was really important; why did you edit it out?

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned *tmp to head. But I can see that head had always been NULL. So the loop is never entered, and nothing is being inserted to the list.

So what we'd need to do it first initialize head to a node instance

```
typdef struct node 
{
    char* data;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
}node;

head = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

then we assign it data.

```
head->attribute = value;
```

finally we set this pointer location value to our tmp pointer as well.

```
tmp = head;
```

no we can proceed with our loop

strings in C are represented as an array of chars, whose stored location points to the first element of the char array. the array must also end with a NULL chat '\0'. note that strlen(str) will return length of string without the NULL char so you must add 1 while mallocing to take this into sconsideration. i would advise not messing with strings unless absolutely necessary. by that I mean trying to manually manipulate them. this will introduce another set of problems not related to what we're working on in general. we should just use strncar(), strncpy() methods until c style strings become completely intuitive.

Comment: How would you go about implementing this? when I am trying I am just getting more issues.

Comment: looks at your lines of code ```struct node* tmp = head;    while(tmp)```. we have understood that here ```tmp == NULL``` and therefore will never enter the loop. so it will never be added. do we agree on this part?

Comment: so, we have to make it such that head is not null, but an instance of our linked data structure node. right?

Comment: therefore, we'll malloc sizeof(our node) for head, then proceed to initialize the head node's values like head->some_attribute = some_value. we do this for ALL the attributes of our node item. then we assign it to the tmp var. and move forward. i haven't fully read into the code, but i predict that it might crash because your implementation probably needs to pass a ```double pointer``` to actually register an insert - but let's try to address the head issue first.

Comment: this reference site will help you become familiar in a short time: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/

Comment: ok, I think I understand the concept but no clue how I would go about implementing everything to get it to work. I have tried hours of trial and error and even assistance from friends but always end up with it not doing anything, which is where I am now stumped and overwhelmed. And I have actually tried using that website as well.

Comment: there are some errors in your code, let me come back to you in some time.

Comment: Also, take note that you never malloc-ed your char pointer. so it expires after local scope is over. meaning it does not retain data.

Comment: and the first insertion to a linked structure is a special case, not like the insertion of other nodes. im on a new system, so it is just taking me a while to debug the code on windows' atrocious notepad

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry this is my first larger project, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out!

Comment: no worries, but i'm trying to think how to best show you the information. you've made some terrible mistakes that must be corrected immediately otherwise they will impact your performance later. i'll highlight them and share them as an image.

Comment: Yea I would appreciate it, I thought it would be a more simple fix of just me not printing to file correctly. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: i have some other work to do, so i might have to get back to you later. but in the meantime, i'd recomment you implement this logic in a flexible programming language like python. there are two sets of errors here. one is due to the nature of c, other is due to logic. it would be more convenient if we know that your implementation of the linked structure is correct. then we can address the C aspect of things.

Comment: Yea that's totally understandable, whenever you have a chance. I don't know python, just fairly new to coding. I know the linked list should work fine because it worked with the hardcoded list I implemented, that is why I assumed the issue is with the printing.

Comment: the problem with c is that things are ```passed by value``` so you cannot expect to pass a SINGLE pointer in all cases and make change to something. there is the concept of multiple level pointers that hold locations of other pointers. if you are new, please look into and become comfortable with java first. if you attempt to learn c without proper reference or guidance, you might learn wrong things, which is what happened do me. then it becomes hard to correct incorrect habits. start with java, then move onto c, you wont even need to learn python then you'll get it anyway.

Comment: Ok, will definitely try that before tackling my next project!

Comment: Tried getting a better understanding through Java, but still have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood right your question. I tried to fix the program like it will read a file and make a list of the data in the file.

I fixed some issues;

1. For the `transverse` function, i added a for loop and printed the data using `%c`.

   ```
   while (temp != NULL) {
       for(i=0; temp->data[i]!='\0'; i++) {
       printf("%c\n", temp->data[i]);
      }
       temp = temp->next;
   }
   ```
2. I changed the `insertAtEnd` function like this;

   ```
   void insertAtEnd(FILE* f, char* data)
   ```

And naturally, in main function, calling this function changed like;

```
    insertAtEnd(ifp, result[i]);
```

By the way for the following statement, my complier wanted me to express the `temp` as `char`, it said it was the first use of this. It also seems like you entered a space after `&`.

```
    insertAtEnd(ofp, &temp);
```

3. I added the following statements to the `main` function;

   ```
   argc -= optind;
   argv += optind;
   ```
4. I also changed this `ifp= fopen(ifilename, "r");` statement with this `ifp= fopen("ifilename.txt", "r");`statement. I opened a text file named `ifilename.txt` and wrote some data there.

EDIT:
Ok so if you want to print the strings to an output file and you want to print the words in the lines individually, you will change the code doing the following things:

1. I changed the struct's data with an array, gave it an expected maximum line length with a sharp defined `MAX_LEN`;

   ```
   struct node
   {
     char* data[MAX_LEN];
     struct node *prev;
     struct node *next;
   };
   ```
2. I changed the `insertAtEnd` function again because I scanned the file in main function, made an array of the strings, sent it to this function and added it to the end of the list. I used this piece of code in main fuction:

   ```
   char* result[count];
   char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   while (fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), ifp))
   {
       result[count] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
       strcpy(result[count], temp);
       insertAtEnd(result, count);
       count++;
   }
   ```

`count` is the number of strings in the file. I also sent this number to `insertAtEnd` function;

```
void insertAtEnd(char* data[], int size)
{
  //Create a new node
  struct node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newnode->data[size] = data[size];
      if (newnode->data[size] != NULL) {
...
```

3. I wanted to use the output file you opened in the `main` function, so I sent this file and sent the `count` -number of strings- to the printing function `transverse` like this;

   ```
   void traverse(FILE *of, int size)
   {
     int i;
     // List is empty
     if (head == NULL) {
       printf("\nList is empty\n");
       return;
     };
     // Else print the Data
     struct node* temp;
     temp = head;
     while (temp != NULL) {
       for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
         fputs(temp->data[i], of);
         temp = temp->next;
       }
     fprintf(of, "\n");
     }
   }
   ```

Also in `main` function, calling this function will be changing like;

```
traverse(ofp, count);
```

Comment: Wow, this helps a lot, thank you I now understand what mistakes I was making! If I were to want it to print to an output file instead of terminal how would I implement that? Would I write an if statement at the end and just put ofp= fopen("outputfile.txt", "w"); ?

Comment: That's correct and use `fprintf()` instead of `printf()`.

Comment: ok great, now how would I get the output to print each word individually and then go down a line instead of going down a line after every letter? I can only seem to get either this output or have everything jumbled together on one line.

Comment: Great stuff if that helped you @extra. For the last question, I believe you should change the `data` element of the list with an array, something like `data[MAX_LEN]` and before all of that, `define` a `MAX_LEN`, give it an expected maximum line length. And to avoid the program stopping when it comes to the new line, you should going to open the file with append mode, using `fopen("file.txt", "a")`. Well the code changes again for that particular problem, I will need time to write that.

Comment: @extra so I finally found some time to edit the answer for the questions you asked so check it out, i hope it helps.